# Set_relation_n_n grocery crud and condeigniter and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysql-error-1064

I have a problem when i use set_relation_n_n in grocery crud

The problem is that the mysql tells me that the query that the database to retrieve the data has bad syntax for MySQL 5.6.23 is the version of my server. and do not know where I can find a solution that does not allow me to edit the fields in the system

I put the two tables in conflict

> TABLE `Docente_Escuela` (   Id_afiliadoint (11) NOT NULL,
>     Id_escuelaint (11) NOT NULL,   Priorityint (11) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`id_afiliado`,`id_escuela`) )
>  ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT
>   CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_swedish_ci;

the other

> TABLE `Escuela` (   Id_escuelaint (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     Numerovarchar (10) NOT NULL utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE, 
>   `Name`
>   varchar (200) NOT NULL utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE, 
>   Domiciliovarchar
>   (100) NOT NULL utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE, 
>   Id_nivelint (11) NOT
>   NULL,   Id_modalidadint (11) NOT NULL, 
>   Id_ciudadint (11) NOT
>   NULL,  
>  Cod_postalvarchar (30) NOT NULL utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE,
>     Telefonovarchar (50) NOT NULL utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE,
>    Celular
>   varchar (50) NOT NULL utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE,
>    Mailvarchar (100)
>   NOT NULL utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE, 
>   Mail_altvarchar (100) NOT NULL
>   utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE, 
>   Mail_alt_2varchar (100) NOT NULL
>   utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE, 
>   Observacionesint (11) NOT NULL,
>     Clave_cobrovarchar (10) NOT NULL utf8_spanish_ci COLLATE,
>     `Status` tinyint (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'   PRIMARY KEY
>   (`id_escuela`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE =
>   utf8_spanish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 2;

and table affiliate

> TABLE `Afiliado` (   Id_afiliadoint (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `Name` varchar (100) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE, 
>   Apellido
>   varchar (100) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE,
>    Documento
>   varchar (11) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE, 
>   Domiciliovarchar
>   (200) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE,
>    Id_situacionint (11) NOT
>   NULL,   Id_localidadint (11) NOT NULL, 
>   Id_provinciaint (11)
>   NOT NULL, 
>   Cod_postalvarchar (30) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci
>   COLLATE, 
>   Telefono_fijovarchar (30) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci
>   COLLATE, 
>   Telefono_altvarchar (30) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci
>   COLLATE,  
>  Celularvarchar (30) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE,
>     Mailvarchar (100) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE,
>    Mail_alt
>   varchar (100) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE, 
>   Clave_cobro
>   varchar (20) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE, 
>   Valor_cuota
>   varchar (20) NOT NULL utf8_spanish2_ci COLLATE,
>    `Status` tinyint
>   (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'   PRIMARY KEY (`id_afiliado`) ) ENGINE =
>   InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci
>   AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;

so I call on the system

> $ Crud-> set_relation_n_n ('Schools', 'Docente_Escuela', 'School',
>   'id_afiliado' 'id_escuela', 'name', 'priority');

and this is the error

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the Manual That
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE `` Escuela`.`id_escuela`id_afiliado` =' 5 'ORDER BY
>   `Docente_Escuela`.`pri' at line 3
>
> SELECT * FROM `s7a675883 name as Docente_Escuela` Escuela`ON LEFT
>   JOIN` `Docente_Escuela`. Id_escuela = `` `WHERE` Escuela`.`id_escuela
>   `id_afiliado` = '5' ORDER BY `Docente_Escuela`.`priority`
>
> Filename: models / Grocery_crud_model.php
>
> Line Number: 336

Someone can give me a hand where I can advance? I'm locked

Thank you!!
Bruno

Comment: Check the missing comma in your `$crud->set_relation` between `'id_afiliado'` and  `'id_escuela'` .

Comment: Thanks!! I clean the white spaces in the sentences and works fine now!! thanks!!

Comment: happy to be helpful. I added my comment as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on your crud call.

Check the missing comma in your `$crud->set_relation` between `'id_afiliado'` and `'id_escuela'`.